# Como transformar uma string no formato Date no R?

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

No código abaixo as datas estão no formato: Mes Dia Ano. Preciso que o R reconheça a variável como data.

```r
#importa os dados
library(XML)
u<-"http://espnfc.com/team/fixtures/_/id/205/season/2012/brazil?cc=3888"
tab<-readHTMLTable(u,header=T,skip.rows=1)    
dados<-tab[[1]]

#Cria a variavel data
ano=2012
dados$DataAno<-paste(dados$Date,ano)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Um pacote interessante é o `lubridate` [(CRAN)](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/index.html).

No seu caso você vai usar a função `mdy()`  (month, day, year), e dizer que a data está em inglês:

```r
library(lubridate)
dados$DataAno <- mdy(paste(dados$Date,ano), locale="en_US.UTF-8")
```

Note que se a data estivesse em formato diferente bastaria mudar a ordem das letras da função, como, por exemplo, ano, mês dia:`ymd()` (year, month, day), e assim por diante.

Answer (score 4):

Para armazenar DataAno como [Date](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Dates.html) você pode mudar a última linha para

```r
dados$DataAno <- as.Date(paste(ano, dados$Date), format = "%Y %b %d")
```

os parâmetros de [format](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html) servem para indicar que o string está no formato:
%Y: ano
%b: mês abreviado (jan, feb, ...)
%d: dia (decimal entre 01 e 31)

"%b" pode ser um problema porque isso depende da região que está configurada. No meu caso

```r
Sys.getlocale(category = "LC_TIME")
[1] "en_US.UTF-8"
```