# Como declarar constantes no R

Tags: r, constantes

quando fui reproduzir o exemplo da questão "[Como transformar uma string no formato Date no R?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8196/1271)"
o comando

```r
tab<-readHTMLTable(u,header=T,skip.rows=1)
```

falhou. O erro aconteceu porque no meu ambiente é natural atribuir a `T` o valor
do período que estou analisando. Por essa razão, no meu ambiente, `T` não é sinônimo de `TRUE` e o comando falha.

Isso me fez perceber que corro o sério risco de acidentalmente digitar `pi = 7`, o que acarretaria em sérios erros de análise.

A pergunta é como declarar `pi` como uma constante?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função `lockBinding`:

Por exemplo:

```
pi <- base::pi
lockBinding("pi", globalenv())
```

Isso vai travar a variável `pi` na constante `base::pi` interna no global environment. Assim se você tentar definir uma nova variável `pi` no ambiente global com outro valor, o sistema não irá deixar:

```
pi <- 5
Error: cannot change value of locked binding for 'pi'
```

Comment: Não é mais seguro a primeira linha ser pi <- base::pi?

Comment: Sim, é mais seguro, vou alterar!